# Remove 'Administrators' from 'Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services' policy using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Powershell script to remove 'Administrators' from the 'Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services' local policy (on Windows Server 2012), leaving only the Remote Desktop Users group.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how I could go about doing so? Or if I could edit it from the registry using Powershell?

Comment: Why not use the GPO?

Comment: You know that an admin can just switch back whatever you change right? What are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: I'm writing a script to automate the setup of a remotely controller build server. I'm looking through the GPO commands which look like they will do the trick but I can't seem to install the Group Policy Management Console module, I've tried: 

'Install-WindowsFeature –Name GPMC', 
'Import-Module servermanager', and
'Add-WindowsFeature –Name GPMC'

Comment: Then I would ask that question on ServerFault and fix the right problem.